# Console.log returns function instead of array

Tags: javascript, events

I have an event and callback being set up in one function, when I try to log the return value I am expecting the array returned from the callback since the event is triggered immediately but instead I am logging the function itself.
Where am I going wrong?

```js
findFraudByFromID = (fraudID) => {
  this.KYCinstance.getPastEvents('ReportedFraud',{
  filter: {fromID: fraudID},
  fromBlock: 0
  }, (error, events) => {
    var frauds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      frauds.push(events[i].returnValues.fraudID); 
    }
    return frauds;
  })
} 

trackFraud = (fraudID) => {
  console.log(findFraudByFromID.bind(this, fraudID))
}

trackFraud()
```

Comment: `bind` function returns a new function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind` will create a new function with `this` available in the function. So what you want to do it run the function to get the returned array.

```
console.log(findFraudByFromID.bind(this, fraudID)());
```

or

```
console.log(findFraudByFromID.call(this, fraudID));
```

Comment: `console.log(findFraudByFromID.bind(this, fraudID))();` must be this `console.log(findFraudByFromID.bind(this, fraudID)());`

Comment: But that begs the question, why use `.bind()` at all instead of `.call`? Like `findFraudByFromID.call(this, fraudID)`. With `.bind()` you're unnecessarily creating an intermediate function object that is only invoked once.